# how to fix LookupError: base64 in python3 while running String decode() Method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

I am running below program in python3, but getting an error

```
Str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
Str = Str.encode('base64','strict');
print ("Encoded String: " + Str)
print ("Decoded String: " + Str.decode('base64','strict'))
```

and getting Error is:-

```
File "learn.py", line 646, in <module>
    Str = Str.encode('base64','strict');
LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

Comment: And have you tried to implement what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Also, why not just use the `base64` module?

Comment: yes i just now i tried base64 module but did not get desired output

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes brother i tried but getting same error

Comment: You don't include that information *in your question* however. Did you check the [documentation for the `base64` codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms)?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is not a string encoding method, its a method for encoding bytes use the [base64 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) instead

Comment: dear could you tell please how can I use base64 module in above program

Answer (score 0):

Encode and Decode `base64` (using more than required variable so that everyone can keep track of operations).

```
import base64
print("base64 Encoded/Decoded string \n")
str="this is a test string "
s1=str.encode('ascii')  # it will result like: b'this is a test string'
s2=base64.b64encode(s1);   #storing value before printing
print("encoded : ",s2)
print("decoded : ",base64.b64decode(s2)) #direct conversion
```